# Unable to login due to broken key on built-in keyboard

Tags: keyboard, login

The <kbd>0</kbd> (zero) key on my MacBook's built in keyboard stopped working. I am unable to login as the password contain that character.

Do I need to get an external USB keyboard to login? Is there an on screen keyboard that can be invoked without logging in? I have a 201 MacBook Air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An external USB keyboard will allow you to log on. Then you can change your password using the external keyboard, and you will be able to log on with the internal keyboard again. But you won't be able to type the character <kbd>0</kbd> ever again, unless you get the keyboard fixed.

Comment: Just plug in USB keyboard and it will accept it ? do nt want to spend money on something that does not work. Just want to get the data from it.

Comment: It should just work. And USB keyboards cost very little money for a basic model. Perhaps borrow one from a friend for 30 minutes?

Comment: There supposed to be a shortcut keys to bring up accessibility keyboard on the screen.

Comment: You can try and use Siri or voice dictation (tapping the function key twice) as well. The accessibility can't be brought up unless it's enabled in the settings. USB keyboard is the best option though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't display the virtual keyboard, but still can change the keyboard layout at the login screen, choose Unicode Hex, or some keyboard layout entry with a similar name. Then you can enter each character by holding option key and entering the four digit hex code. For instance the number '0' would be entered with option + 0030.

Answer (score 0):

In the top-right corner you should be able to change the keyboard layout. Change it to `Dvorak - Left-Handed` this will move every number key like the below:

[image: Dvorak - Left Handed]

If you were using a `U.S.` layout, your `.` key will now type `0`. Change it back to your old layout for the rest of your password.